# Как реализовать подчеркивание и изменение цвета первой буквы в слове

Tags: html, css

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 40pt;
  margin: 10% 0 0 10%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

h3::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 85px;
  background-color: #000;
}

h3:first-letter {
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Siblime
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 40pt;
  margin: 10% 0 0 10%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

h3::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 85px;
  background-color: #000;
}

h3:first-letter {
  color: #ffc600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Siblime
</h3>
```